# Can't call Fragment method in parent Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

I simply want to call a method from a fragment in my MainActivity(parent).
But as soon as I try to call the method I get an NullPointerException.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> com.example.fragmenttest.TestFragment.testMethod()' on a null object
> reference

Here is what I do in the onCreate of the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TestFragment()).commit();



    TestFragment fragment = (TestFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.testfragment);
    fragment.testMethod();
}
```

and here is the fragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment,container,false);

    return  rootView;
}

public void testMethod(){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">



    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and activity_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/testfragment">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:text="Fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course this is not my real project, I just created a new one to simplify my issue.
In my real project I want to call a method from my fragment as soon as the onRewardedVideoCompleted method gets called, which is in my MainActivity.

How do I call the method from my fragment without getting a null pointer exception and without using an interface? (Using an interface for this small problem seems unnecessary)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`commit()` is asynchronous. This is why your project is crashing upon launch. Instead of using `commit()`, use `commitNow()`. Also, instead of using `new TestFragment()`, create a variable so you can call its methods.

```
TestFragment testFragment= new TestFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, testFragment).commitNow();

testFragment.testMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment transactions are asynchronous (unless you use executePendingTransactions()). Your transaction has likely not completed yet. You use runOnCommit on FragmentTransaction (in the support library) to execute code after it is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

TestFragment yourFragment = newe TestFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, yourFragment).commit();

yourFragment.testMethod();
```

First of all, You must pass `yourFragment` to `fragmentTransaction`, then you can call any methods you want.

Comment: This is not correct. The toast message will not be able to get a context so it will crash.

Comment: You can get context into fragment by ```getContext()``` method.

Comment: commit() is asynchronous. getContext() will not return a context if the fragment manager is not done.

Comment: So write ```contractor``` method for fragment and pass Activity ```context``` to fragment and use it.

Comment: By ```contractor``` bro, write a ```contractor``` method into fragment like that

```
private Context context;
public OrderFragment(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
}```

Comment: If you want to pass in the context from the parent activity, then yes that would work.